# Excel based data processing

Tags: database, excel, vba

Here's a brief explanation of my problem related to defect counting. 
Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E

Column A and B are binary (defect present or absent). Column C contains description of defect. Column D contains predefined list of defects

If cell in Column A is 0 ---> return 0 in column E.
If cell in column A is 1 ---> check if cell in column B is also 1.

If cell in column B is 1 ---> insert 0 in cell E.

If cell in column B is 0 ---> check whether description in Column C matches description in column D.

If description matches ---> return 1 in cell E.

If description does not match ---> return 0 in cell E.

I used a couple of IF and VLOOKUP functions for the above but I got a "too many functions" error from excel.

Could someone please help me frame a formula / VB code for this?

Comment: First make your best attempt at this, and if you encounter errors/problems - you can post a more direct question. As it is now, it does not seem you have done anything yet.

Comment: As @ishmaelMakitla pointed out: This isn't a _Code 4 me_ platform. Please post code and consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I apologize if I havent followed the general rules. Am new to stack overflow. will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim startRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet


startRow = 1  'Set first row to check
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = startRow To lastRow
    If sh.Cells(i, 1) = "0" Then
        sh.Cells(i, 5) = "0"
    ElseIf sh.Cells(i, 1) = "1" And sh.Cells(i, 2) = "1" Then
        sh.Cells(i, 5) = "0"
    ElseIf sh.Cells(i, 1) = "1" And sh.Cells(i, 2) = "0" Then
        If sh.Cells(i, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 4) Then
            sh.Cells(i, 5) = "1"
        Else
            sh.Cells(i, 5) = "0"
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

What you want is a little bit unclear, does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Ill quickly work with this and, if the problem persists, get back to you with a better framed question!

Comment: If this works for you, accept the answer to close down the question. :)